# Generics in java, extending interfaces

Tags: java, interface, extend

In the code below:

```
class A<T extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB>
```

what does it mean "T should be a type of InterfaceA"?

for example the next code:

```
class A<T extends Number>
```

means that T can be an int, a double or any other numeric types.
can anyone give me an example to explain the first code?

Comment: Have you tried it in your IDE and see what you get from it?

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions, `InterfaceA` not `interfaceA`.

Comment: yes i have tried it, but I don't understand what does it mean? does an interface has any type that T extend from it?

Comment: @Shakiba-Check my code,I hope it helps you understand why only a specific type can be passed which implements both interfaces, interfaceA and interfaceB in your case!If you don't understand,please point to me!

Comment: @shekharsuman- It was clear, I got the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class A<T extends interfaceA & interfaceB>` means

that T is bounded by two interfaces. Thus,any type argument passed to T must implement `interfaceA` and `interfaceB`.

Sample program for your understanding :-

```
interface X{
public void eat();
}

interface Y{
public void drink();
}

class XYZ implements X,Y{
@Override
public void eat(){
    System.out.println("I am eating.");   
}
@Override
public void drink(){
    System.out.println("I am drinkin too!");
}    
}

class A<T extends X & Y> {
public void display(){
     XYZ x=new XYZ();
     x.eat();
     x.drink();
     System.out.println("Type of XYZ is "+x.getClass().getName());
    }  
}

public class Sample1{
public static void main(String[] args) {
 A<XYZ> a=new A<>();
 a.display();
}    
}
```

This means that type which argument passed to T must implement interfaces X and Y.

Like shown in the given code :-

`A<XYZ> a=new A<>();  //here only XYZ(substituted in place of T) can be passed because it implements both interface X and interface Y`

I hope this much helps you understand and point out the differences!!!

Comment: I tried it in my IDE, but it has a problem with the line A<XYZ> a=new A<>();

Comment: @Shakiba-Which version of Java are you using? And also,which IDE+ which line or what error are you facing???

Comment: @Shakiba-Would you mind accepting the answer so that both of us can earn reputations!Please consider only if you were satisfied with my answer!

Comment: @Shakiba-You can upvote my answers too,if satisfied,please!THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

It says `T` must be a type that implements both `interfaceA` and `interfaceB` interfaces.

Your second example says that `T` must be of any type that implements the `Number` interface only.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with @shekhar suman's example, but i would change last class and main:

```
class A<T extends X & Y> {
  public void display(T t){
       t.eat();
       t.drink();
       System.out.println("Type of T is "+t.getClass().getName());
  }  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   A<XYZ> a=new A<>();
   a.display(new XYZ());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there was no extends like this: 
    Class A<T>
Class A was a generic class, accepting any class T.

However in case of 
    Class A<T extends InterfaceA & InterfaceB> 
T can be any class that implements both interfaceA and interfaceB.

In other words you want to make sure T is not any random class, and satisfies some conditions.